# can't compile with libpqxx and xcode4 (c++)

Tags: c++, xcode4, libpqxx

I am trying to use libpqxx (3.1) in my C++ project in order to connect to my postgresql database. I am using the lastest version of xcode (xcode 4).

I correctly made the install (./configure, make and make install) and added the library in my header search path and library search path.

header search path : /usr/local/include
library search path : /usr/local/lib

Then,

```
#include <pqxx/pqxx>
```

And i get the following error in the pqxx/cursor.hxx file:

```
  stateless_cursor(
    transaction_base &trans,
    const PGSTD::string adopted_cursor) :
    **m_cur(trans, adopted_cursor, up, op)**
  {
    // Put cursor in known position
    m_cur.move(cursor_base::backward_all());
  }
```

No matching constructor for initialization for 'internal::sql_cursor'

Should I edit this file ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I edited the library and changed:

```
 m_cur(trans, adopted_cursor, up, op)
```

to :

```
m_cur(trans, adopted_cursor, op)
```

to match the constructor signature.